# How do you get iPlayer to work on Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, windows-rt, microsoft-surface, iplayer

I thought Internet Explorer on Windows 8 RT had a version of Flash to allow playback of various streaming services, including BBC iPlayer and 4OD. They both don't seem to work. Can this be fixed?

Comment: [Wasn't working straight out of the box but doing a update resolved the issue and it works perfect.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfusing/will-microsfot-surface-rt-play-bbc-iplayer-in-the/4ff85ebc-dd3e-4399-b0e1-16453fa88af4). No idea what was updated though.

Comment: I've done an App Store update (and just checked to make sure nothing new available) and it's still not working in IE. Is there another update to try?

Comment: This is all the information I was able to find.

Comment: It does have a built-in Flash but it only supports websites on a whitelist.  This is true also on the x86-64 Modern UI IE 10.  My understanding there isn't a desktop version of IE on Windows RT.

Comment: @ChrisF Found it. You need to type 'Update' at the Start screen to bring up Windows Update. When you check for updates there's a 'Flash Update' which sorts out the playback issues on BOTH iPlayer and 4OD. Since you pointed me in the right direction post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound There is a Desktop version of IE on Windows RT.

Comment: @snowdude - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfusing/will-microsfot-surface-rt-play-bbc-iplayer-in-the/4ff85ebc-dd3e-4399-b0e1-16453fa88af4) there's the same question.

The answer (and I quote) is:

> Wasn't working straight out of the box but doing a update resolved the issue and it works perfect.

I would suggest running Windows Update to make sure you have the latest versions of everything - including the whitelist of sites allowed to run Flash.